# Too many rerenders when I use fetch hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

when I try to fetch data from the server, I have 4 data responses in my web console instead of 1.
This is my code

```
export default function SelectTableComponent() {
    const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetchCaseStudy();

    console.log(data);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {isLoading && <div>A moment please...</div>}
            {error && (
                <div>{`There is a problem fetching the get data - ${error}`}</div>
            )}
            {data && <DataGrid
                columns={columns}
                rows={data}
            />}
        </div>
    );
}

export function useFetchCaseStudy(): useFetch.FetchResult<caseStudy[]> {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch<caseStudy[]>(
    `https://..../case-study`,
  );

  return { data, isLoading, error };
}
```

I would like to have just one response

Comment: What do you mean by *"...four "data" responses..."*? Please copy and paste what you're actually getting from the context ([as text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247), not a screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to see that `console.log` executed at least twice:

1. Once when the component first renders (on mount), before the `fetch` is started
2. Again when the component re-renders because the `fetch` completes (either with data or an error) *(okay, technically if it **never** completes you won't see this, but I'm assuming it completes)*

It's probably repeating that cycle a second time because of [`StrictMode`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) in development. In `StrictMode`, certain operations that are supposed to be pure are synthetically repeated (to prove that they're pure).

Comment: okay, thank you for the answer. Yes, I really have strict mode turned "ON" in my project